# Frequency table but custom function instead of default count?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame:

```
bla <- data.frame(
  a = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
  b = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0),
  c = c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0),
  d = c(2,3,4,7,8,6,5,2,1,0)
)
```

I can use table() to get the counts of each combination of 1/0 for each of a, b and c:

```
table(bla %>% select(a:c)) %>% as.data.frame()

  a b c Freq
1 0 0 0    1
2 1 0 0    2
3 0 1 0    1
4 1 1 0    1
5 0 0 1    0
6 1 0 1    3
7 0 1 1    2
8 1 1 1    0
```

Here's my question, is there a approach to get back both the frequency AND the mean of column d for each combination of a, b and c?

I.e. it looks like `table()` auto groups by each distinct combination then returns `count()` (Freq field). Can I do the same but add mean()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base `R` solution using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(d ~ ., data = bla, 
          FUN = function(x) c('mean' = mean(x), 'count' = length(x)))
```

And, the **`dplyr`** package could also be handy (this would be my preference):

```
library(dplyr)
bla %>%
    group_by(a, b, c) %>% # or group_by_at(-vars(d))
    summarise(count = n(),
              mean_d = mean(d))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want also the non-present combinations, with `dplyr` and `tidyr` you can do:

```
bla %>%
 complete(a, b, c) %>%
 group_by_at(1:3) %>%
 summarise(count = sum(!is.na(d)),
           mean = mean(d))

      a     b     c count  mean
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0     0     1  0   
2     0     0     1     0 NA   
3     0     1     0     1  7   
4     0     1     1     2  4.5 
5     1     0     0     2  4.5 
6     1     0     1     3  3.67
7     1     1     0     1  2   
8     1     1     1     0 NA
```

Comment: Are you sure that the other solution provides all of the combinations? Or you have been interested just in combinations actually present in the data?

Comment: In this particular case just combinations that exist in the data but today I learned about complete() function so thank you! Hopefully if someone else lands here this will be helpfull

Comment: OK, I just needed a clarification to see whether I answered the right question :)

Comment: Might be cleaner to do `count = sum(!is.na(d))`